# Unable to find obfuscated Firebase class in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Yes, sadly I'm working on a project that's still being worked on using Eclipse. I'm integrating this with Firebase and I read this about getting the aar file working with Eclipse ([How can I use Firebase cloud message in an eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37792333/how-can-i-use-firebase-cloud-message-in-an-eclipse-project/37891421)), and everything is doing ok except the following:

I'm able to import several classes in the jar file:

```
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;
```

but when trying to extend `FirebaseMessagingService` I get the following error:

```
The type com.google.firebase.iid.zzb cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

I peeked into the jar file and I can see other classes but not those. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Ok, found the error.

I'm importing just the `firebase-messaging` aar, but should also import `firebase-iid`.

Comment: i am getting the same error , but i have imported firebase-iid library still not able to import the packages for FirebaseMessagingService and InstanceIDListenerService , even i have tried for import com.google.firebase.iid.InstanceIDListenerService and it shows me 
The import com.google.firebase.iid.InstanceIDListenerService cannot be resolved