# Not getting notification using Firebase in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've got Firebase building without any warnings using Eclipse (see related: [Unable to find obfuscated Firebase class in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39258216/unable-to-find-obfuscated-firebase-class-in-eclipse/))

I try to send a test notification, however I'm not getting anything. I'm using a library project as well. This is my code:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application />
    ... 
    <!-- ==================================
               FIREBASE
    =================================== -->
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIdService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
....
</application>
```

These files are practically straight from the samples:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    public static final String PUSH_NOTIFICATION_TEXT = "pushnotificationtext";

    private static final String TAG = "Firebase";

    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // Handle data payload of FCM messages.
        String messageId = remoteMessage.getMessageId();
        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

        Log.d(TAG, "FCM Message Id: " + messageId);
        Log.d(TAG, "FCM Notification Message: " + notification);
        Log.d(TAG, "FCM Data Message: " + data);

        sendNotification(this, notification.toString());

   }

    // Put the GCM message into a notification and post it.
    private void sendNotification(Context context, String message) {

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        final Intent intent = new Intent(context, Splash.class);
        //intent.putExtras(bundle);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        //Save push notification message to show when app starts
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        sp.edit().putString(PUSH_NOTIFICATION_TEXT, message).commit();

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVibrate(new long[] { 0, 500, 200, 500, 200, 500 })
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            .setContentText(message)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).setOngoing(false);

        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

Other class:

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "Firebase";
    private static final String FRIENDLY_ENGAGE_TOPIC = "friendly_engage";

    /**
    * The Application's current Instance ID token is no longer valid 
    * and thus a new one must be requested.
    */
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // If you need to handle the generation of a token, initially or
        // after a refresh this is where you should do that.
        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "FCM Token: " + token);

        // Once a token is generated, we subscribe to topic.
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(FRIENDLY_ENGAGE_TOPIC);
    }
}
```

I send a message via the Firebase console targeting the package name with no luck. I'm uncertain what I should do to get this to work. Do I need to use the `google-services.json` file in some way?

Thanks

Comment: Use Android Studio

Comment: I can't, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Eclipse and am not able to verify that these steps work.  I hope they will get you started on the right path.

The Firebase framework is initialized by [FirebaseInitProvider](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/provider/FirebaseInitProvider).  You don't need to implement or subclass it. Just declare it in your manifest.

```
    <provider
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.firebaseinitprovider"
        android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:initOrder="100" />
```

`FirebaseInitProvider` expects to find string resources that contain the configuration values for the project. In an app built with Android Studio and the [Google Services Gradle Plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin), the resource values are created from the `google-services.json` file.  Because you are not using AS and the plugin, you will need to define these resources in your `res` folder.  The values can be found in your Project Settings at the Firebase Console or in the `google-service.json file`. Because you are only interested in messaging, some values may not be needed.  To be safe, define them all initially.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="default_web_client_id" translatable="false">8888888888888-ooqodhln4cjj4qst7b4sadfiousdf7.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
    <string name="firebase_database_url" translatable="false">https://project-888888888888888.firebaseio.com</string>
    <string name="gcm_defaultSenderId" translatable="false">888888888888</string>
    <string name="google_api_key" translatable="false">AIzaSyB0Bhr1sfsydfsdfnwelhkOYifak_Go2xU</string>
    <string name="google_app_id" translatable="false">1:888888888888:android:526f9740dfg987sdfg</string>
    <string name="google_crash_reporting_api_key" translatable="false">AIzaSyDkG-g8hH7T4TV7Rrsdfgiopudfmn234897</string>
    <string name="google_storage_bucket" translatable="false">project-8888888888888888888888.appspot.com</string>
</resources>
```

You can confirm that the initialization succeeded by putting this code in the `onCreate()` method of your main activity:

```
    FirebaseOptions opts = FirebaseApp.getInstance().getOptions();
    Log.i(TAG, "onStart: ID=" + opts.getApplicationId());
    Log.i(TAG, "onStart: SenderId=" + opts.getGcmSenderId());
    Log.i(TAG, "onStart: Key=" + opts.getApiKey());
```

If valid results are logged, it indicates the default [FirebaseApp](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp) has been initialized, and you should be able to receive messages.

Comment: Great stuff, I'm trying this out now. How does the JSON file translate into XML? For example I'm seeing values like  {
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "75794",
    "firebase_url": "https://this-is-a-test-project.firebaseio.com", etc

Comment: @zundi:  I think the mapping you are looking for is in the Google Services Gradle Plugin doc I linked in my answer.

Comment: @zundi:  What was the final outcome of this.  Did it work for you?