# Implement FCM Using eclipse in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like to integrate FCM push messaging service using eclipse. Somehow I'm not able to use Android studio. I found plenty of answers but all these are not solid answer. Mostly answered with "Use Android Studio" that's not appropriate answer for question.

see related:

[Not getting notification using Firebase in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280746/not-getting-notification-using-firebase-in-eclipse)

[Unable to find obfuscated Firebase class in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39258216/unable-to-find-obfuscated-firebase-class-in-eclipse/)

[How can I use Firebase cloud message in an eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37792333/how-can-i-use-firebase-cloud-message-in-an-eclipse-project/37891421)

Currently I managed those two jar from firebase (iid & messaging) inside libs but no idea how to config "google-services.json" inside eclipse.

I raise this question cause there is not solid and complete answer for this. So please don't mark this duplicate humble request. I know this is big challenge for who stopped using eclipse since Android Studio arrived.

Comment: There is google services plugin for Eclipse (afaik). Instead you can initialize the FirebaseApp in your code as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634767/how-to-connect-to-more-than-one-firebase-database-from-an-android-app/37643374#37643374

Comment: I think the real question here is why does Android Studio not work for you? There is no reason it shouldn't work. Eclipse is not supported anymore. That's why do many things don't work with Eclipse. Android Studio replaced Eclipse a few years ago now, switching is your only option.

Comment: AS working for me but somehow I don't want to use AS anyway thanks @XaverKapeller

Comment: Frank's answer is the simplest.  If that doesn't work for you, maybe take a look at this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39283789/4815718.  It worked for me, but the user who tried it never confirmed it worked for him.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen can you elaborate. Where should I need to place these values in "res" another question problem is with this line --android:authorities="${applicationId}.firebaseinitprovider"

Comment: Read the answer I linked in my first comment. The values are in code there.

Comment: I don't get it actually can you show me small sample it will be great. I really stuck at this please help.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen can you please provide the sample code for fcm implementation in eclipse. I have followed your all posts but not working. please help me.