# I want to implement Push Notification in Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to implement Push Notification  in Android. So which method is Better for Push Notification? Using GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) or
FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging)?

I recently read somewhere GCM is shutdown from Sept 2016, so running GCM for new User. So which one is using GCM or FCM.

Answer (score 2):

Google encourages you to use FCM. So you should use FCM.

> "Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) is the new version of GCM. It inherits
>   the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus new features!"

Link: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq

Answer (score 2):

From [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)

> Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) is the new version of GCM. It inherits the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus new features! See the FAQ to learn more. If you are integrating messaging in a new app, start with FCM. GCM users are strongly recommended to upgrade to FCM, in order to benefit from new FCM features today and in the future.

So clearly FCM is the way to go now.

Comment: Thanks For Ans : I have using Eclipse. so FCM is possible for Eclipse?

Comment: There is answer to your question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37792333/how-can-i-use-firebase-cloud-message-in-an-eclipse-project

Answer (score 2):

[Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) (FCM) is the newer version of [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) (GCM). So it is *strongly* recommended that *new* users (developers) to use FCM.

In relation to that, it is only possible to generate Server Keys by creating a Firebase Project:

> Starting from September 2016, you can create new server keys only in the Firebase Console using the Cloud Messaging tab of the Settings panel. Existing projects that need to create a new server key can be imported in the Firebase console without affecting their existing configuration.

This is probably the note you've read. This doesn't really say that GCM is *shutdown*.