# Is it possible to use Firebase in Eclipse like in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, firebase

I tried to work with Firebase in Android Studio but I got too much Problems. Now I want to know if it is possible to use Firebase in Eclipse.

Comment: copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37792333/how-can-i-use-firebase-cloud-message-in-an-eclipse-project

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase in Eclipse up to Kitkat supported devices