# Push Notification OneSignal (front-end), and Firebase (back-end)

Tags: android, eclipse, firebase, push-notification, onesignal

Is it possible to use OneSignal for Push Notification as Front-End and Firebase as Back-end, in Android?
I trying to explore OneSignal because it possible to build in eclipse.
Because I have a project android using Eclipse IDE, and if I use firebase as my front-back-end for push notification I need to move to Android Studio.

Or did anyone have a clue to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used oneSignal.But i have used Android Studio which is now almost used by almost everyone and i feel that eclipse is outdated.You can surely import eclipse project to Android studio without any issues.Also firebase is easy to use.You can use OneSignal in Android Studio [as mentioned here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup)

Comment: Yes everyone told me to use Android Studio, but I need more time to move and test. So is it possible to use Firebase in Eclipse? Any tutorial ?

Comment: [see this link.....u might sometime get issues....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37319236/use-new-firebase-sdk-in-android-eclipse-project?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: [How can I use Firebase cloud message in an eclipse project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37792333/how-can-i-use-firebase-cloud-message-in-an-eclipse-project/37891421#37891421)

Comment: Thanks sir. Your link give me great information for using Firebase on Eclipse.